# Where is Scalaz Bind.bind implemented?

Tags: scalaz7

I am curious where the method `scalaz.Bind.bind` is implemented? Thanks

```
trait Bind[F[_]] extends Apply[F] { self =>
  ////

  /** Equivalent to `join(map(fa)(f))`. */
  def bind[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]
  ...
```

I am looking at 7.3.0-SNAPSHOT source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bind` follows typeclass pattern, and those tend to have multiple implementations for different types that support operations defined by them. That implementations called typeclass instances. Most of the Scalaz typeclass instances for Scala standard library classes reside in `scalaz.std` package. Examples:

`Bind[List]`: `listInstances` implicit value in `scalaz.std.ListInstaces` trait, defined in scalaz/std/List.scala. It can be imported via `scalaz.std.list` object (in the same file) or `scalaz.Scalaz` object (in scalaz/Scalaz.scala), both of which extend the `ListInstances` trait.

`Bind[Option]`: `optionInstances` implicit value in `sclaaz.std.OptionInstances`, defined in scalaz/std/Option.scala. It can be imported via `scalaz.std.option` object (in the same file) or `scalaz.Scalaz`  object (in scalaz/Scalaz.scala), both of which extend the `OptionInstances` trait.

You can also create Scalaz typeclass instances for your own types by creating implicit values or conversions that implement one or more corresponding traits. To be visible, implicits must be imported into your context.